# Excel truncating column of csv file when length of character in column is more than 255 characters

Tags: excel, csv

I am sending data to client in csv format. Some of the text column have length more than 255 characters which get truncated when opened in excel. 
I can't use the suggestion mentioned in some other questions on stackoverflow like adding space before as we sending the data to client.

As suggested in https://superuser.com/a/318421

> "=""Data Here"""

Even this doesn't help if number of characters is greater than 255.
It would be great to know some work around for this.
Thanks in Advance.
P.S.: This is my first question.

Comment: Can you post some samples of the type of content getting truncated? Have you tried copying the data to Google Sheets and exporting as CSV?

Comment: Excel has a column width max of 255.  However, it can hold a string length up to 32,767 characters.  So your data is probably still there, you just can't view it all in the cell.  See here for Excel limits: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Comment: The data should be viewable in the formula bar.  If you need it to display the complete string in a cell, you may need to use a different csv viewer than Excel.  Or you may need to split the contents of the longer cells into multiple separate cells for viewing purposes while hiding the column with the original data.  The workaround that you choose will depend on what you need the data for.